How do we reference the dbContext from the Application layer in DDD for queries?
Here are the assumptions that I have gathered via extensive research:

"Domain models are separate to persistence entities."
"Repository Pattern's best use-case is on the command (write operation) side of things as it allows you to load an aggregate as a whole."
"For queries (read operations) there is not much benefit and may possibly be counter-intuitive to add an abstraction over Efcore (such as with the Repository pattern)."

So now I'm left with the Core layer having domain models, the infrastructure layer with persistence entities and the application layer with Data transfer objects that map persistence entities and domain models to the presentation layer.
This is all made sense to me until I realised that in order for my application layer queries to use the dbContext, I needed a dependency on the Infrastructure layer. However, the infrastructure layer has a dependency on the app layer for things like Auth, Logging, ObjectStorage, etc. Leading to a circular dependency error.
I can't define an "IAppDbContext" interface in the app layer as the app layer does not know about the persistence entities defined in the Infrastructure layer.
Curious to know what the solution to this might be?
The solutions I thought about are:

Define a service per query in the application layer and implement it in the infra layer. But as you can imagine, this might be very inconvenient.
Split infrastructure layer into two layers: infrastructure & persistence layer and allowing application to depend on persistence, clearing the circular dependency error but it feels like a hack.

I obviously understand that I should sometimes "break the rules" as certain things work better in theory than in practice, but the purpose of this question is to explore the solutions others might be using.

DbContext's are "light weight"; you create them when you need them; use them; then dispose of them. You don't sit on them; or share them. If you need the same query "results" in more than one place, put "that" one in a "repository". But yes, wrapping "everything" just becomes tedious; so just have a dbContext "factory" when not accessing "the repository".

Your Program is the DI composition root that will need to reference everything. You could move that to its own assembly if you want to be really pedantic about dependencies. But I wouldn't bother.

Personally I follow a fairly DDD approach (by no means a purist:) using a repository pattern at the aggregate root level. The repository handles factory methods for creating entities. (ensuring all required values are provided and any lookups are valid and accounted for) Read operations are done via the repository exposing IQueryable results so that callers can further filter, sort, paginate, and project results. The repository itself enforces core rules like authorization checks/filters, and other details like disabling global filters where needed. (i.e. viewing deleted data in soft-delete systems) To work with IQueryable efficiently with deferred execution I make use of a Unit of Work pattern that the repository can discover for access to a scoped DbContext. (DbContextScope by Medhime, [Zejii.DbContextScope for EF Core])
All read operations involve projection down to view models which manage UI translation and logic. The entities are solely responsible for representing the data domain.
Ultimately it comes down to what your real requirements are. I do not recommend abstracting EF "away" entirely from your domain unless there is a distinct business value for that. For example if you want a separate service wrapper for data access that works with DTOs and commands that can be called by a web application, series of APIs, and other services then that would warrant a more concrete form of abstraction. However, abstraction for the sake of abstraction puts a straight-jacket on the development savings and performance that EF can provide when you can fully leverage features like projection rather that inefficient services that return standard materialized sets of data.
My main "Don'ts" for working with EF, DDD or otherwise:

Don't use Generic repositories: Generic methods are suited where the target types are completely interchangeable. A repository for (A) will have different requirements from a repository for (B) or (C). Generic repositories form a lowest common denominator for working with the data domain resulting in inefficient and/or complex code.
Don't abstract for the sake of abstraction: Writing an abstraction layer around EF "just in case" EF needs to be swapped out (too slow) is a self-fulfilling prophecy. The resulting abstraction will not leverage many of the capabilities of EF leading to slow and complex code. Abstracting to try and
"hide" EF-isms again leads to inefficient code or complex code like Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> parameters that still need to conform to EF-isms. If you want to leverage EF in a solution, trust it.

Circular dependencies can be managed using contract interfaces in a common assembly that are injected/resolved by both the application and domain. The application can register implementations of these contracts with the IoC Container which will provide to the domain repositories etc. for logging, authentication, authorization, etc.
I do recommend adpoting bounded DbContexts for things like authorization and  logging if you have a logging solution that will be writing to a database for instance. A bounded DbContext is simply a DbContext with entities registered for that single purpose rather than relying on a single large DbContext. Smaller DbContext instances can be more efficient than a single large DbContext and will avoid issues like poisoning when you might have an exception handler in an application repository that wants to log an exception. The logger uses a LoggingDbContext for instance rather than the ApplicationDbContext so it is unaffected by the invalid tracked changes in the application DbContext.
